# How can I multiply values returned by two different method, inside of the third method?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner, return-value

I am trying to find the buying price of the stock. I can't multiply the `stocksBought` and `stockPrice`.

- **getStocksBought** method returns the number of stocks bought
- **getStockBoughtPrice** method returns the price of one stock while buying
- **getBuyingPrice** method returns the buying price by multiplying the value returned by getStocksBought with value returned by getStockBoughtPrice

Java code

```
public static int getStocksBought(Scanner kb){
    System.out.print("Enter the number of stocks bought:");
    int stocksBought = kb.nextInt();
    return stocksBought;
}

public static double getStockBoughtPrice(Scanner kb){
    System.out.print("Enter the price of one stock when bought: ");
    double stockBoughtPrice = kb.nextDouble();
    return stockBoughtPrice;
}

public static double getBuyingPrice(){
    double buyingPrice = getStocksBought() * getStockBoughtPrice();
    return buyingPrice;
}
```

However I get

```
Method: getStocksBought required: 
    java.util.Scanner found: no arguments 
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length –
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: What's the actual question? What doesn't work?

Comment: the getBuyingPrice method is giving me an error

Comment: @yapancha post your error on your question. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Method: getStocksBought
  required: java.util.Scanner
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: see Elliott Frisch's answer. It's not that your methods aren't multiplying.

Comment: Why are you passing a Scanner object?

Comment: @yapancha please accept Elliot Frisch's answer if it is correct and you approve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your methods require a `Scanner` parameter (and you are not passing one). Something like,

```
public static double getBuyingPrice(){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    double buyingPrice = getStocksBought(kb) * getStockBoughtPrice(kb);
    return buyingPrice;
}
```